# Indenting Java source files using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, indentation

I'm using an UML tool that generates Java classes from the UML class diagram. Unfortunately the code inside is not indented.

How to solve this? How can I indent a file using Eclipse?

Comment: @Logan: soyatec's eUML plugin

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How to indent a Java source file in Eclipse:

1. Open the file in Eclipse's text editor.
2. Ctrl+A to select all text.
3. Ctrl+I to indent the text (or right click > Source > Indent).
4. Ctrl+S to save the file.

Done.

(If you also want to correct the spacing, then use Ctrl+Shift+F or right click > Source > Format. This can be applied to a single file, or a group of files using the Project Explorer pane.)

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Use the code format feature with the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+F in eclipse then you will get the code formatted using eclipse standard and not only indenting. Advanced you can write an xml file to specify your formatting preferences.

/Farmor

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can make the whole process fully automatic by invoking Eclipse plugin from command line:

```
eclipse -nosplash \
  -application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter \
  -verbose \
  -config ~/eworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs \
  MyClass.java
```

Just make sure to create workspace where you have your formatting preferences set up according to your requirements.